# Show checked items into TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to show my multiple checked items into text box.

Creating windows form application and trying to check multiple items from check box list and then showing checked items into text box

```
private void Button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
    {
      textBox5.Text += i;
    }
    else
    {

    }
  }
}
```

I want my checked items into TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

I got very close to output 
my code :

```
string message = "";
            foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
                textBox5.Text += "Name: " + row["Table_Name"];
                message += Environment.NewLine;
            }
```

Comment: You didn't document your question that you have a DataTable as the source of your CheckedListBox.

Comment: may i get output like selected item 1 and selected item 2 into two different label???

Comment: CheckedListBox doesn't support multiple selected items.  The language is important: are you talking about multiple "checked" items?

Comment: Anything is possible. It's not clear from your description what you want to happen.

Comment: foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
                textBox5.Text += "Select * From " + row["Table_Name"] ;
            }   i want run query like {SELECT * 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;  }  so for that i want both selected table into two different variable so that i can use